# What was Riff Raff drinking?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show, rocky-horror-show

Riff Raff sings:

> I remember doing the Time Warp
>   Drinking those moments when
>   The blackness would hit me
>   And the void would be calling

I've always interpreted this as Riff Raff drinking, *savouring*, the moments. But it occurred to me that it could also mean that he was drinking *during* those moments. Less poetic and a bit more alcoholic.

So which interpretation is correct? Or was he perhaps *literally* drinking the moments? He is, after all, a Transsexual Transylvanian.

Comment: ... and perhaps the blackness literally crept up behind him and physically struck him while he was distracted with a very audible call from the void.

Comment: We see him swilling champagne straight from the bottle as he gets into the elevator, but I would be shocked to hear that "drinking" means anything other than "absorbing" in the lyrics to *Time Warp*.

Comment: I always interpreted it as Riff being drinking during the time warp and collapsing because of that... But I may be a little alcoholic myself ^^

Comment: I have always thought it was about you know.... *sex*